# MATLAB urlwrite to save google search results with latitude / longitude

Tags: matlab, latitude-longitude

when I search for a research affiliation and add latitude longitude, google search returns a page with the values of both latitude and longitude, but when I use MATLAB's urlwrite for example the part with latitude and longitude is not in the final html saved.

```
clc
clear
close all

strURL = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=Imperial+College+London+latitude+and+longitude';
strFile = 'ICL-UK.html';

web(strURL)
urlwrite(strURL, strFile)
web(strFile)
```

the two webpage shown are sligthly different, i.e missing the lat/lon infos